# Date time conversion in javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript

I am getting different `time conversions` while using a `datetimepicker` in `js` and converting the `date` in `php`

My **PHP** code is:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s A',strtotime('5/29/2013 00:00PM'));
    //outputs 1970-01-01 05:30:00 AM
    //echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s A',strtotime('5/29/2013 0:00AM'));//same result
    //tested on http://writecodeonline.com/php/
?>
```

And **js**

```
<script>
    var s='5/29/2013 0:00PM';
    parseDate= function(s) {
        var currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, currentHour, currentMinute;
        arr=s.split(' ');
        dateArr=arr[0].split('/');
        currentYear=dateArr[2];
        currentMonth=parseInt(dateArr[0])-1;
        currentDay=dateArr[1];
        timeArr=arr[1].split(':');
        currentHour=timeArr[0];

        if(s.contains('AM')===false)
        {
            currentHour=parseInt(timeArr[0])+12;
            currentMinute=parseInt(timeArr[1].replace('PM'));
        }
        else
        {
            currentMinute=parseInt(timeArr[1].replace('AM'));
        }
        console.log(currentYear,currentMonth,currentDay,currentHour,currentMinute,0,s.contains('AM'));
        return new Date(currentYear,currentMonth,currentDay,currentHour,currentMinute,0);

    }
    console.log(new Date());
    alert(parseDate(s));
    //outputs Wed May 29 2013 12:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
</script>
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/36vjH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because strtotime does not support your format ('5/29/2013 00:00PM');

Try: strtotime('2013-5-29 00:00:00); or http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php instead.

Comment: So how do I convert the `string` in `strtotime compatible` in `php`?

Comment: as i mentioned you can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php this method

Comment: Like `$d=DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:iA','5/29/2013 0:00:PM');
echo $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");` **Great Thing**

Comment: It is not true that strtotime does not support the format `mm/dd/y hh:MMmeridian`; it's just that the values have to be in the licit ranges.

Answer (score 1):

The time '00:00PM' is malformed; as documented, an hour `hh` with meridian has the format `"0"?[1-9] | "1"[0-2]`, i. e. not zero, but one to twelve.

Answer (score 0):

This extract from the PHP manual might be relevant:

"*Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.* "

(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)